# Does StampedLock.writeLock() release a read-lock held by the current thread?

Tags: java, concurrency

http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/04/30/java8-concurrency-tutorial-synchronized-locks-examples/ contains this code:

```
StampedLock lock = new StampedLock();
long stamp = lock.readLock();
try {
  if (count == 0) {
    stamp = lock.tryConvertToWriteLock(stamp);
    if (stamp == 0L) {
      System.out.println("Could not convert to write lock");
      stamp = lock.writeLock();
    }
    count = 23;
  }
  System.out.println(count);
} finally {
  lock.unlock(stamp);
}
```

The author writes:

> Calling `tryConvertToWriteLock()` doesn't block but may return a zero stamp indicating that no write lock is currently available. In that case we call `writeLock()` to block the current thread until a write lock is available.

Regarding the case where `tryConvertToWriteLock()` fails, did I miss something or is the author acquiring a read-lock, followed by a write-lock, and never releasing the read-lock?

Further, won't `lock.writeLock()` deadlock waiting for the current thread to release its read-lock?

Comment: The code above almost exactly matches the example code in the documentation, I'd assume you missed something. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/StampedLock.html

Comment: @markspace the documentation shows that when `tryConvertToWriteLock()` fails, the user releases the read-lock before acquiring a write-lock. The article does not release the read-lock.

Comment: Interesting question.  I looked at the code in grepcode and didn't find any evidence that `tryConvertToWriteLock` releases the read lock if it fails to acquire the write lock.  Only if it is successful is the existing read lock upgraded.  However I'm no expert on these low-level operations so I'm posting this as a comment instead of an answer.  The fact that a "tutorial" contains such an error indicates how hard all this is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the code sample provided by the article is buggy. According to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/StampedLock.html

> Like Semaphore, but unlike most Lock implementations, StampedLocks **have no notion of ownership**. Locks acquired in one thread can be released or converted in another.

Further, they provide the following sample code:

```
void moveIfAtOrigin(double newX, double newY) { // upgrade
    // Could instead start with optimistic, not read mode
    long stamp = sl.readLock();
    try {
        while (x == 0.0 && y == 0.0) {
            long ws = sl.tryConvertToWriteLock(stamp);
            if (ws != 0L) {
                stamp = ws;
                x = newX;
                y = newY;
                break;
            }
            else {
                sl.unlockRead(stamp);
                stamp = sl.writeLock();
            }
        }
    } finally {
        sl.unlock(stamp);
    }
}
```

Notice how they release the read-lock before acquiring a write-lock.

Comment: Fell into the same trap almost 3 years later.Asked the same question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/65705957/3835632
 Thanks to your answer.