# Java 8 Stamped Lock: Why this piece of code doesnt result into a deadlock?

Tags: multithreading, java-8, optimistic-locking, optimistic-concurrency, stampedlock

In my attempt to understand Optimistic locking in Java 8,I came across the below piece of code.
[Original Blog Here](https://winterbe.com/posts/2015/04/30/java8-concurrency-tutorial-synchronized-locks-examples/#stampedlock).

As explained in the blog, this piece of code is attempting to convert a read lock into a write lock.The code requests an explicit write lock if conversion of read lock to write lock failed.

It puzzles me **How can it be expected that the explicit write lock get granted when the parent thread is already holding a read lock?** It doesn't look like the read lock is getting released at any point before a write lock is forcefully requested. To my flawed understanding, the thread would wait infinitely for write lock as the read lock is never released creating a deadlock.

**Why this doesn't result in a deadlock here?**

```java
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
StampedLock lock = new StampedLock();

executor.submit(() -> {
    long stamp = lock.readLock();
    try {
        if (count == 0) {
            stamp = lock.tryConvertToWriteLock(stamp);
            if (stamp == 0L) {
                System.out.println("Could not convert to write lock");
                stamp = lock.writeLock();
            }
            count = 23;
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    } finally {
        lock.unlock(stamp);
    }
});

stop(executor);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Its more a theoretical question actually. Why the writelock gets granted when the thread is already holding a readlock given that Stampedlocks are non reentrant? I do not face any problem with this piece of code.Just trying to understand the reasoning explained in the blog.

Comment: To all readers, Here's the same issue highlighted differently and with an answer
https://stackoverflow.com/q/49216525/3835632

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?  From the API for `tryConvertToWriteLock`

> If the lock state matches the given stamp, atomically performs one of the following actions. If the stamp represents holding a write lock, returns it. **Or, if a read lock, if the write lock is available, releases the read lock and returns a write stamp.** Or, if an optimistic read, returns a write stamp only if immediately available. This method returns zero in all other cases.

Comment: So here, in the case I am highlighting, write lock isnt available. So this returns a zero timestamp. The code should then asks for a write lock. As I understand it, the write lock wouldnt be granted unless the read lock is released which is held by the same thread leading to deadlock. Only possibility I can imagine is `tryConvertToWriteLock` causes release of read lock when it is called even if conversion is not successful.

Comment: Here's the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49216624/3835632